# How to move text and change it's value at the same time in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, transition

For example, this is what happening right now

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var titleLable = "This is basic text"
    @State var isTextAnimated: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(titleLable)
                .offset(y: isTextAnimated ? 300 : 0)
                .animation(.linear)
            Button {
                isTextAnimated.toggle()
                if isTextAnimated {
                    titleLable = "New text appeared"
                } else {
                    titleLable = "This is basic text"
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Press")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
```

The code above leads to this in Live Preview:
[click there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD65o.gif)

This happens if text doesn't change its value ( I need this behaviour with changing ):
[click there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze0F6.gif)

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest way to achieve this animation is to embed two `Text` inside a `ZStack`and modify their opacity, and modify the ZStack's offset rather than the individual Texts. in this way both the offset and the change between two texts will get animated. here is my code:

```swift
struct HomeScreen: View {
    @State var isTextAnimated: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Text("Hello")
                .opacity(isTextAnimated ? 1 : 0)
            Text("World")
                .opacity(isTextAnimated ? 0 : 1)
        }
        .offset(y: isTextAnimated ? 150 : 0)
        
        
        Button(action: {withAnimation{isTextAnimated.toggle()}}){
            Text("Press")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: ✅ This gives a much smoother animation than my answer, using `matchedGeometryEffect`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to  `.matchedGeometryEffect` to animate moving and changing value of `Text` view you can "rasterize" text using `.drawingGroup()` modifier for `Text`. This makes text behave like shape, therefore animating smoothly. Additionally it's not necessary to define separate with linked with `.machtedGeometryEffect` modifier which can be impossible in certain situation. For example when new string value and position is not known beforehand.

### Example

```swift
struct TextAnimation: View {
    var titleLabel: String {
        if self.isTextAnimated {
            return "New text appeared"
        } else {
            return "This is basic text"
        }
    }
    
    @State var isTextAnimated: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(titleLabel)
                .drawingGroup()  // ⬅️ It makes text behave like shape.
                .offset(y: isTextAnimated ? 100 : 0)
                .animation(.easeInOut, value: self.isTextAnimated)
            
            Button {
                isTextAnimated.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Press")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: Text's value and position animating]

### More informations

[Apple's documentation about .drawingGroup modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/drawinggroup(opaque:colormode:)/)

Answer (score 0):

edit: I forgot to animate the text change

```swift
struct AnimationsView: View {
    @State private var buttonWasToggled = false
    @Namespace private var titleAnimationNamespace

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if !buttonWasToggled {
                Text("This is some text")
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "text", in: titleAnimationNamespace)
                    .transition(.opacity)
            } else {
                Text("Another text")
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "text", in: titleAnimationNamespace)
                    .transition(.opacity)
                    .offset(y: 300)
            }

            Button("Press me") {
                withAnimation {
                    buttonWasToggled.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

A good way to animate such change is to animate the offset value rather than toggle a boolean:

```swift
struct AnimationsView: View {
    @State private var title = "This is basic text"
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Some text")
                .offset(y: offset)

            Button("Press me") {
                withAnimation {
                    // If we already have an offset, jump back to the previous position
                    offset = offset == 0 ? 300 : 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or by using a boolean value:

```swift
struct AnimationsView: View {
    @State private var title = "This is basic text"
    @State private var animated = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Some text")
                .offset(y: animated ? 300 : 0)

            Button("Press me") {
                withAnimation {
                    animated.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note the important `withAnimation` that indicates to SwiftUI that you want to animate the changes made in the block. You can find the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/withanimation(_:_:))

The `.animation(...)` is optional and used if you want to change the behavior of the animation, such as using a spring, changing the speed, adding a delay etc... If you don't specify one, SwiftUI will use a default value. In a similar fashion, if you don't want a view to animate, you can use add the `.animation(nil)` modifier to prevent SwiftUI from animating said view.

Both solutions provided result in the following behavior : https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlSw1.jpg

Comment: These solutions only animate the text offset. The OP requires the text string itself to also change

Comment: Yeah, the main problem is to make this animation also when text value is changing

Comment: My bad, I've updated my solution to use `geometryEffect`.  Ashley Mills' solution is the correct one but I've updated my answer just in case people read it : )

Answer (score 0):

To animate the position *and* the content of the `Text` label, you can use `matchedGeometryEffect`, as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isTextAnimated: Bool = false
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if isTextAnimated {
                Text("New text appeared")
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "title", in: namespace)
                    .offset(y: 300)
            } else {
                Text("This is basic text")
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "title", in: namespace)
            }
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    isTextAnimated.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Press")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```